# Using xsl to transform single XML doc to multiple docs

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

Given the following xml document:

```
<XML>
<doc1>
</doc1>
<doc2>
</doc2>
<XML>
```

I was hoping to use an xsl transform to generate 2 XML documents:

```
<XML>
<doc1>
</doc1>
<XML>
```

And

```
<XML>
</doc2>
<doc2>
<XML>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: hey Oded, you beat me to it - editing xml on an iphone not so easy!

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for both XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0 solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In XSLT 1.0 it isn't possible to create more than one tree as the output of any transformation**, but in XSLT 2.0 this can be done really easy.

In XSLT 1.0 one could use the **[`<exsl:document>`](http://exslt.org/exsl/elements/document/index.html)** extension element of EXSLT.

Or, one can have a transformation, that is provided a global (and externally specified) parameter, containing the element name of the element that must be extracted into a single document:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pDocElement" select="'doc1'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*">
  <xsl:if test="name()=$pDocElement">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="copy"/>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node()" mode="copy">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document (based on the provided one):**

```
<t>
    <doc1>
  Doc 1 Content
    </doc1>
    <doc2>
  Doc 2 Content
    </doc2>
    <doc3>
  Doc 3 Content
    </doc3>
</t>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
<doc1>
  Doc 1 Content
</doc1>
```

**And you will run this transformation once for every element, whose sub-tree should be extracted into a separate document**.

---

**Here is an XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="copy">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*[starts-with(name(),'doc')]">
  <xsl:result-document href="{name()}.xml">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="copy"/>
  </xsl:result-document>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document (based on the provided one):**

```
<t>
    <doc1>
  Doc 1 Content
    </doc1>
    <doc2>
  Doc 2 Content
    </doc2>
    <doc3>
  Doc 3 Content
    </doc3>
</t>
```

**The result is correctly output to three documents**:

```
Saxon 9.1.0.5J from Saxonica
Java version 1.6.0_21
Stylesheet compilation time: 868 milliseconds
Loading net.sf.saxon.event.MessageEmitter
Writing to file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre6/bin/doc1.xml
Writing to file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre6/bin/doc2.xml
Writing to file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre6/bin/doc3.xml
Execution time: 151 milliseconds
Memory used: 11467936
NamePool contents: 18 entries in 18 chains. 6 prefixes, 6 URIs
```

Comment: +1 Excellent answer including XSLT 1.0 without extensions solution!

Answer (score 0):

We had that problem once and solved it by slightly cheating:

step 1: create one big file containing different xml scripts separated by program instructions or comments.
step 2: use a program to cut the file into separate files.

Note that your intermediate result is invalid xml, but the end result is valid.

**Example**

```
<doc1>..<doc1>
<!-- SEP -->
<doc2>..<doc2>
<!-- SEP -->
<doc3>..<doc3>
```